# Can you fillet the base of an object without needing supports? Is there a recommended radius?

Tags: 3d-design

I am currently adding a fillet to the base of an object (the plane that's touching the bed) and I was curious if the radius of the filet contributed to any mis-prints. I've had luck so far but was wondering if the intensity of the radius had mattered.

I am using the Ender3 Pro.

---

*I may do some test prints and see for myself and provide an answer to share experience .*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can print a fillet without support as support material causes other issues like problems with removing supports and ugly scarring on you print. However, a fillet will cause an overhang when you slice the object

[image]

and may result into poor results as well, see e.g. this:

[image]

If your design allows it you should better use a chamfer than a fillet for the base of the print object.

A chamfer prints better than a fillet because a fillet creates an overhang (see indicated area on the left part of the image below.

[image]
*Image from [3DVerkstan](https://support.3dverkstan.se/article/38-designing-for-3d-printing#:%7E:text=It%27s%20important%20that%20you%20use,printer%20will%20handle%20very%20nicely.)*

A chamfer, which normally is a 45° straight cut-off, doesn't create an overhang and, as such, prints better. If you still want a fillet, you could start with a chamfer of which you fillet the top, see the right part of the image above.

A chamfer with the height of the first and second layer is generally a good idea to reduce the slightly over “squished” first layer issues that create a lip around the base of the part.

Comment: The sag is not just "due to gravity". It would happen equally upside down or in zero gravity, because it's due to not having any surface to press the extruded material against. You only get the desired rectangular cross section of extrusion (e.g. 0.4 mm wide by 0.2 mm thick) when there's a surface to constrain where the material goes. Otherwise you get a roughly circular cross section whose Z dimension is greater than the layer height.

Answer (score 0):

> wondering if the intensity of the radius had mattered.

Yes it does if it's an overhang.